# NFA to an RE Kleene's Theorem

Tags: regex, finite-automata, computation-theory, nfa

Here is my NFA:

[image: NFA]

Here is my attempt.

- Create new start and final nodes
- Next eliminate the 2nd node from the left which gives me ab
- Next eliminate the 2nd node from the right which gives me ab*a
- Next eliminate the 2nd node from the left which gives me abb*b
- Next eliminate the 2nd node from the right which gives me b+ab*a

Which leads to abb*b (b+ab*a)*

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Which one is start node and which one is end node?

Comment: Check out this post for the method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676431/regular-expressions-with-repeated-characters/13677120#13677120

Answer (score 1):

No you are not correct :(

<sub>you not need to create start state. the first state with `-` sign is the start state. Also `a,b` label means `a` or `b` but not `ab`</sub>

<sub>there is a theorem called [Arden's theoram](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=MKeF4o5o5JAC&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=Arden%27s%20theorem&source=bl&ots=Vw6_elgkxM&sig=_crZR56Yk7R1MGGKI30tp_HfeLA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=49cLUaG1BsforAejoYDgCQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Arden%27s%20theorem&f=false), will be quit helpful to convert NFA into RE</sub>

**What is Regular Expression for this NFA?**

In you `NFA` the intial part of DFA:

**step-1:**

```
(-) --a,b-->(1)
```

means (a+b)

**step-2:** next from stat 1 to 2, *note* state 2 is accepting state final (having `+` sign).

```
(1) --b--->(2+)
```

So you need  `(a+b)b` to reach to final state.

**step-3:** One you are at final state `2`, any number of `b` are accepted (any number means one or more). This is because of self loop on state `2` with label `b`.

So, `b*` accepted on state-2.

**step-4:**

Actually there is two loops on `state-2`.

- one is self loop with label `b` as I described in **step-3**. Its expression is `b*`
- second loop on state-2 is via state-3.
  the expression for second loop on state-2 is `aa*b`
  **why expression `aa*b` ?**

  because:

  ```
            a-  
            ||               ====>  aa*b
            ▼|   
  (2+)--a-->(3) --b-->(2+)
  ```

So, In step-3 and step-4 because of loop on state-2 run can be looped back via `b` labeled **or** via `aa*b` ===>  `(b + aa*b)*`

So regular expression for your NFA is:

`(a+b)` `b` `(b + aa*b)*`

Comment: I left some obvious explanation. let me know if you have other doubts. You can find some more helpful question on `RE` and `FA` via my profile