# Match if there is a X in the first and X the second Y can be 0

Tags: regex

I am currently working on a program. I need a regex that takes Y and X and that pairs of X is separated by Y. It does not have to be equal numbers, but it cannot contain multiple X'es on side of each other.

Examples:

```
# Don't match:
XXXYYYYY
#Match:
XYXYYYY
X
```

My try so far:

```regex
{Y*[X|^X]Y*[X|^X]Y*}*
```

The problem is that if there is a X in the first and X in the second the Y still can be 0. Can i directly test for double X's?

Comment: @almasshaikh Have updated the question

Comment: Why not test directly for `XX` and reject when found?

Comment: @Unihedron That was not the point, for you to react on that, sorry, but all i need is some theory that i maybe can test for double X's or something like that

Comment: What kind of RE you are looking for? [tag:Perl] style regex, or [tag:awk] style ERE, or the plain RE used by [tag:sed]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's so *unusual* about it?

```
^(?:X(?!X)|Y)+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tR9bD1/1)

Explanation: it's just a series of X and Y where an X cannot be followed by another X (negative lookahead).

Comment: Since `Y` is logically going to appear equal or more than the amount of `X`s, changing the alternation to include `Y` in the front may make it slightly more efficient in matching the input.

Comment: @Unihedron You can even do better: `^(?:Y++|X(?!X))+$` or `^(?:(?>Y+)|X(?!X))+$` but since OP didn't specify the regex flavour I left that optimization out.

Comment: Insighted comment and great point! However as a point of note, in PCRE `Y++` is defined as the same as `(?>Y+)`.

Comment: Yes, but for instance, the possessive quantifier modifier (`++`) is not available in .NET so you have to use atomic groups (`(?>...)`)... again, everything depends on the flavour :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the answers above uses look-ahead, this answer present a solution in vanilla regular expression:

```
^(X?Y)*X?$
```

The solution above assumes empty string is allowed. Otherwise:

```
^((X?Y)+X?|X)$
```

(Feel free to make the groups non-capturing)

Thanks to Unihedron for the simplification `XY|Y` to `X?Y`.

---

If anyone still have doubt about the validity of this answer, [solve the below equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676431/regular-expressions-with-repeated-characters/13677120#13677120):

```
R1 = XR2 + YR3 + λ
R2 =       YR3 + λ
R3 = XR2 + YR3 + λ
```

The DFA can be drawn from the equations above.

Remove the `+ λ` in `R1` if empty string is disallowed.

Comment: Following a bit of logical induction, you'll have `^(X?Y)*X?$` which would work best. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*?XX)X[YX]*$
```

Try this.This should fulfill your requirement.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/8

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
^Y*(XY+)*X?$
```

if you want to ensure that there is at least one character, you can check the length separately or add a lookahead at the begining:

```
^(?=.)Y*(?:XY+)*X?$
```

about catastrophic backtracking:

If you use a DFA regex engine there is no problem since there is no backtracking.

if you use a NFA regex engine, you can prevent the catastrophic backtracking with several ways, examples:

```
^Y*(XY|Y)*X?$       # possible but not really efficient

^Y*(?>XY+)*X?$      # using an atomic group (if available)

^Y*(?:XY+)*+X?$     # using a possessive quantifier (if available)

^Y*(?=((XY+)*))\1X?$ # emulate `(?>(?:XY+)*)`

^Y*(?:(?=(XY+))\1)*X?$  # emulate `(?>XY+)*`
```

Comment: Interesting theory, though for the sake of not burning up users' code with catastrophic backtracking, better mention using `(?> )` instead of `(?: )` where the language supports it :)

Comment: `^Y*(XY|Y)*X?$` Drop the first `Y*` (since `Y*` is already covered in the `(XY|Y)*` and the solution will be the same as mine. The rest are redundant, since `^(XY|Y)*X?$` will never have backtracking problem.

Comment: @nhahtdh: `^Y*(XY|Y)*X?$` can be indeed shorten to `^(X?Y)*X?$`. However this pattern stay less efficient since the number of steps before failing is 4x greater than patterns that use atomic grouping. So they are not redundant at all. So, with unihedron simplification, the most efficient pattern is `^(?>X?Y+)*+X?$`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I can't observe 4x difference. However, I do see a 2x difference if I use `^(X?Y)*+X?$`. The `(?>` is unnecessary when possessive quantifier is used. Anyway, it is still linear regardless.

Comment: @nhahtdh: you will better see the 4x difference with these links: http://regex101.com/r/tN7cN9/1 http://regex101.com/r/yZ5jX7/1 . Indeed, `^(?:X?Y+)*+X?$` should suffice.

Comment: Oh, there is a `+` after `Y`. The number of steps doesn't reflect the number of characters in the string scanned. Since `(X?Y+)*+` and `(X?Y)*+` on `YYYYY` input both requires a scan on all characters involved, but `Y+`'s scan records as 1 step, while `(X?Y)*+`'s scan records as at least 5 steps (or more). The slowdown probably does happen, though, when the engine creates state for the `X?Y` pattern for every Y and XY, while `X?Y+` only create state for every X.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yes, but the difference decreases when the proportion of X tends to 50%.