# Regular expression deppending on number of characters and presence of specific characters

Tags: regex, symbols

My alphabet is `{0,1}`. I want to match a token with an odd (or even) number of symbols, but it must contain at least one `0` and at least one `1`. I tried this regular expression:

> `^(?=0*?1)(?=1*?0)[01](?:[01]{2})*`

but it matches `11111` if the input is `111110` and it is not correct.

Comment: If you anchor both sides, it should be correct.

Comment: @nhahtdh, I dont't think I understand what you mean by "anchor".

Comment: Ok, but in this case if my input is `111100`, I have no match and I shoud have `11110`.

Comment: So what is your question? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this sounds like automata theory, so here is an answer based on that.

You should be able to come up with the 7-state DFA below:

[image]

<sup>Click on the image to see enlarged version.</sup>

The DFA on the left is for even length string and the one on the right is for odd length string. The label on the state is "[current length (odd or even)]/[0 encountered][1 encountered]".

Then you can [solve the equation for the final state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676431/regular-expressions-with-repeated-characters/13677120#13677120)... or just use [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org/) to do all that for you.

Regular expression for odd-length string (can be used in your favorite regex flavor):

```
((11)+0|(00)+1|(10|01|(11)+10|(00)+01)[10])([10]{2})*
```

And for even-length string:

```
(10|01|(11)+(10|0[10])|(00)+(01|1[10]))([10]{2})*
```