# Regular expression of string of a, b that doesn't contain aa

Tags: regex

Using only parenthesis and * symbol, one example that comes in my mind is

`((a|b)(bb*))*`

but I can have a string for example abba that the last letter is a, which is not included in this... Any ideas?

Comment: did you mean this `^((a|b)(bb*))*$` ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the DFA:

[image]

[Use the method described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676431/regular-expressions-with-repeated-characters/13677120#13677120) to derive and solve the equation for R1 (the initial state):

```
R1 = bR1 + aR2 + λ
R2 = bR1 + λ
```

Substitute R2 to R1:

```
R1 = bR1 + abR1 + a + λ
```

Apply the Arden's theorem:

```
R1 = (b + ab)*(a + λ)
```

The rest is change the syntax a bit:

```
(b|ab)*(a|)
```

This can be rewritten to regex in Perl-syntax for testing:

```
^(a?b)*a?$
```

Comment: I'll add a graph for the DFA later, but it is derivable from the equation above.