# Can any finite state automata be translated into a regular expression?

Tags: regex, z3, state-machine

Let's assume that we have a fsa as follows:

`fsa = {0:{'a': 1, else: 2},1:{'b': 1, else: 2},2:{else: 2}}`

This means: at state 0, if input is 'a', it goes to state 1, otherwise it goes to state 2; at state 1, if input is 'b', it goes to state 1, otherwise it goes to state 2; at state 2, for any input, it goes to state 2.

Assume, state 0 is a starting state, state 1 is an accepting state and state 2 is the failure state. 
Then this fsa can be translated as regex "ab*". In fact, there are a few algorithms that translate fsa to regex, such as Brzozowski algebraic method.

My question: can any fsa defined in the above form be translated into a regex? Is there any limitation?

Comment: By definition, regular languages are those whose expressive power are equal to some finite state automaton's. (and vice versa)

Comment: One method to convert from DFA to regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676431/regular-expressions-with-repeated-characters/13677120#13677120 (Brzozowski Algebraic Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A every finite automaton will have a corresponding regular expression. Kleene's theorem proves this result. The theorem is proved by using the principle of mathematical induction by partitioning the Finite Automata into the union of a number of smaller Finite Automatas. The proof can be found [here](http://www.cs.may.ie/staff/jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node6.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are mathematically equivalent. '[The equivalence of regular expressions and finite automata is known as Kleene's theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)'

Comment: +1. also the chomsly hierarchy page shows it with a nice perspective : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation - all finite state automata are equivalent to some regular expression, and all regular expressions are equivalent to some finite state automaton.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equivalent.  From the [wikipedia page on regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Equivalent_formalisms), these are all equivalent definitions of regular languages.

1. it is the language of a regular expression
2. it is the language accepted by a nondeterministic finite automaton (NFA)
3. it is the language accepted by a deterministic finite automaton (DFA)
4. it can be generated by a regular grammar
5. it is the language accepted by an alternating finite automaton
6. it can be generated by a prefix grammar
7. it can be accepted by a read-only Turing machine
8. it can be defined in monadic second-order logic (Büchi-Elgot-Trakhtenbrot theorem)
9. it is recognized by some finite monoid, meaning it is the preimage of a subset of a finite monoid under a homomorphism from the free monoid on its alphabet